# Mudar diretório /storage do Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, sistema-de-arquivos, storage

Estou com um problema, usando LARAVEL 8 e o Voyager instalado.
Ao fazer login via SSH no meu servidor compartilhado estou em “public”, seu descer um nível vou para “meusite.com.br” aqui upei todos os arquivos e diretórios do Laravel que em exemplo tem essa estrutura:

```
 /app
 /storage
 ../public/index.php
 /outros
```

Nesse ssh **não** tenho acesso ao php cli para rodar o "php artisan make:link"
Por isso preciso criar um link simbólico da pasta “storage” para a pasta “public” com o comando:
ln -s /storage /public
Porém o comando “ln” também **não** é reconhecido no ssh da umbler.
Como solução pensei em criar o diretório storage dentro da public. Alguém sabe se é possível?. Caso sim como fazer. Caso não, outra sugestão de solução?

Comment: Deu certo ? ...

Comment: @novic Sua dica funcionou, meu sistema agora está pegando as imagens do novo diretório que é uma cópia exata do anterior e também está salvando as novas imagens corretamente.
Contudo estou com um receio da seguinte forma: 
Minha nova entrada no filesystems.php está assim: 
''newstorage' => [
            'driver' => 'local'
            'root' => public_path('newstorage/app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/newstorage/app/public',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ];'

Comment: @novic Sua dica funcionou, meu sistema agora está pegando as imagens do novo diretório que é uma cópia exata do anterior e também está salvando as novas imagens corretamente.
Segue o código:
`        'newstorage' => [
            'driver' => 'local'
            'root' => public_path('newstorage/app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/newstorage/app/public',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ];
`
Contudo estou com um pequeno receio dessa solução que vou descrever em outra pergunta, pois essa vou marcar como resolvida se puder me ajudar lá agradeço. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim é possível trocar o local de gravação das suas imagens para a pasta `public`, abra o arquivo da pasta `config` com o nome de `filesystems.php` e crie um entrada no `array` `disks` com o nome de **storage** e siga o *exemplo*:

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
        
        'storage' => [
            'driver' => 'local'
            'root' => public_path('storage'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ];

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

    ],
```

*Observações:* pode ser qualquer nome, as configurações são essas o `helper` `public_path` e a pasta `public` do seu projeto e o nome dentro `storage` é o nome da pasta dentro da pasta `public`, na verdade foi criado outra entrada para gravar e recuperar arquivos em uma determinada pasta.

---

<sup>***Referencia:*** [File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem)</sup>